# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x0e\xa3' Python

Tags: python, string, tkinter, decimal, pyserial

I get bytes from the serial port which represents the voltage on my PIC board.
But I can't convert these bytes(strings) to decimal because I get the error message above.
Here is the function(in fact, it's associated with tkinter button)

```
def channel8():
    ser.write(chr(0xFF))
    print "you have select channel8"
    x=ser.read(2)
    w=int(x, 16)
    print w
    print "Voltage on channel8 is:" , x
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x0e\xa3'

```
def channel8():
    ser.write(chr(0xFF))
    print "you have select channel8"
    x=ser.read(2)
    z=struct.unpack("h", x)
    #w=int(z, 16)
    print z
```

and i get this :

> Voltage on channel8 is: (28942,)

can you please explain how did i get this value? it's not matching anything :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should use [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct) module and unpack your binary data like this:

```
struct.unpack("h", x)
```

Because `int` is not really for working with binary data, but with hexadecimal strings like: `EF1D`.

When you did `x=ser.read(2)` you received two bytes of binary data, there are two types of number representation supported by `struct` library: `short`(h) and `unsigned short`(H). Function `struct.unpack` receives two argument:

- structure specification (a string of [format characters](http://docs.python.org/library/struct#format-characters))
- binary data

and returns a tuple with unpacked values(only one int in your case).

So you need to change string `w=int(x, 16)` to `w = struct.unpack("h", x)[0]` or to `w = struct.unpack("H", x)[0]`, it depends on data type.

Comment: The example int *could* be unsigned (`'H'`), value 41742, or signed, value -23794..

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you explain more please? i'm a beginer :)

Comment: great, i understand now, 
i put the result of your suggestion in my post (i've edited it)
it gave me a decimal number but it is not matching result.
For example, 0x0E6D gave me 27918 and it should be 3693

Comment: It means that your need to ">h" or ">H" struct specification. It means that uses big-endian byte order.

Comment: what is "h" and x supposed to represent?